# Dependency to a module that packages as war, need the classes

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, war

So i need to have a dependency to a module that packages as a war because it got some classes i need to use. But it gives me an error when i try to build it or run it because it cannot resolve the dependency and cannot find the jar. how do i make it so it can use the module that packages as a war.

I have tried by adding this to my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and the dependency like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
    <artifactId>sleepy-oyster-restorer</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

but it still doesnt work. anyone have a clue?

full pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
        <artifactId>sleepy-oyster-projects</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>sleepy-common-ws</artifactId>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
            <artifactId>sleepy-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
            <artifactId>sleepy-oyster-restorer</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.17</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post all of your pom.xml.

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov added the full pom.xml of the module

Comment: A WAR using as a dependency usually indicates an misusing cause a WAR can't be used on the classpath. The question is: Do you need it as a dependency cause there are classes contained you need or as a dependency?

Comment: @khmarbaise there are classes that i need from there

Comment: Than the thing given in the answer will not work..

Comment: @khmarbaise i added the <type> and it works now

Comment: The build might be not if you require classes from the inside the WAR file...

Comment: @khmarbaise yeah when i try to clean install it complains on that it cant find the things i try to import from the war module. how do i reach the classes from that module?

Comment: The war module must be changed to create separate jar file which contains the classes this can either being done by using `<archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses> furthermore `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses> in maven-war-plugin configuration See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html. But it sound that those classes should be moved to a separate module which would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use a war as a dependency, you need to specify the right `type` for the dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>se.hrmsoftware.hrm</groupId>
    <artifactId>sleepy-oyster-restorer</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

For more information see the [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).